# Css tilda doesn't work if using id and class

Tags: html, css, class, firefox, styles

```css
#header__menu~.header__button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__menu">
  <div class="header__button">
    <div class="header__button-1 header__line"></div>
    <div class="header__button-2 header__line"></div>
    <div class="header__button-3 header__line"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="header__menu">
</div>
```

this code just doesn't work. I have no idea why. I spent like 30 minutes trying to fix it, but I have literally no idea why.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: header__menu has no siblings so the tilde has nothing to select. (Incidentally did you mean to select by class or id? Doesn’t matter in this case as there is nothing to select but might matter in your real life code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tilde is a [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) which means it works on siblings, not parents and children.  Specifically, it works on siblings B that comes after sibling A and has the same parent, where you have A ~ B. So, in your code, if you have

```
.header__button-1 ~ .header__button-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

then .header__button-2 would have a red background. But if you did

```
.header__button-3 ~ .header__button-2 {
  background-color: green
}
```

there wouldn't be anything that really happens. There is no header__button-2 that comes after a .header__button-3.

Comment: I didnt use header__button-1/2/3 in css, im saying about .header__button itself

Comment: Right, I know you didn't, I was just giving an example.  Were you maybe looking for the [Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) instead?  Namely `#header__menu > .header__button`?

Comment: Sorry I just didn't understand your answer first time

Answer (score 0):

Related selectors behave similar to neighboring selectors, but unlike the, style rules apply to all **nearby** elements.

```
.header__button-1 ~ div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: i know but it just doesnt work